# nginx block request for ip number

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx.  If my ip numbers are 1.2.3.4 and 1.2.3.5, how can I configure it to block  requests for the ip numbers and only allow domains.  If site1.com is configured for 1.2.3.4, I want to allow a request for site1.com but deny a request for 1.2.3.4.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a default catch-all virtual host to serve requests for non-configured domains and do whatever you want with these requests. Something like this:

```
# Default vhost
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}

# site1.com
server {
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    server_name site1.com;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to use the ip for multiple domains, so I'm using default_server already for valid sites.  I'm thinking I need to regex match on host name and if it is an ip address, deny.

Comment: Nope, just define your valid domains in *server_name* in the appropriate *server* container - you don't need to set *default_server* for them.